# Array print [0]

Tags: java

I am about to create a code that will generate up number, placed in an array. There after, the two other arrays are created, one for numbers over 500, and an array of numbers below 500. Everything works as it is supposed to be the numbers to be sorted. As you can see on the sheet below, I get only [0,0] even though there are different value to add.

My question is why? What to do about this?

I also wonder how I can get away [] in the result.

(It must be array, not the array list)

Thanks in advance =)

Result:

```
Random numbers: 
[185, 406, 632, 72, 348, 771]
Antal big: 2
big: [0, 0]
Antal small: 4
small: [0, 0, 406, 0]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Code:

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nummer[];
        int big = 0;
        int small = 0;


        System.out.print("Hur många slumptal i intervallet 0-999 önskas? ");
        int x = user_input.nextInt();

        nummer = new int[x]; 
        System.out.println("\nHär är de slumpade talen: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            nummer[i] = (rnd.nextInt(1000));   
            if(nummer[i] > 499){
                big++;
            } else if (nummer[i] < 500){
                small++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Detta gick åt skogen");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nummer));
        //RandomNumber highlow = new RandomNumber();

        int biggest [];
        biggest = new int[big];

        for(int z = 0; z<big; z++){
            if(nummer[z]>499){
                biggest[z] = nummer[z];
            }
        }

        int smallest [];
        smallest = new int[small];

        for(int y = 0; y<small; y++){
            if(nummer[y]>500){
                smallest[y] = nummer[y-1];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Antal big: " + biggest.length);
        System.out.println("big: " + Arrays.toString(biggest));
        System.out.println("Antal small: " + smallest.length);
        System.out.println("small: " + Arrays.toString(smallest));


        //highlow.min(nummer);
        //highlow.high(nummer);
     }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, can you show us what you are expecting in your print statements?

Comment: You have a typo: `if(nummer[y]>500){...}` Should've been `<` (less).

Comment: As a side note: Don't create `Random` object in the loop.  
`Random`  object created in the loop may end up with the same seed. This will cause it to return the same value from `nextInt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd and 3rd for-loop are incorrect. You loop only the number of big and small numbers. Also, you don't need two (or actually any of the loops), but here I've tried cleaning it up a bit:

```
int biggest[] = new int[big];
int smallest[] = new int[small];

int currentBiggest = 0;
int currentSmallest = 0;

for(int j = 0; j < nummer.length; j++){
    if(nummer[j] <= 500){
        smallest[currentSmallest++] = nummer[j];
    }
    else {
        biggest[currentBiggest++] = nummer[j];
    }
}
```

By the way, your code has other minor issues as well. You want an array with numbers bigger than 500 and one with numbers smaller (i.e 499 <), but your if is incorrect. You should also move the `new Random()`-part out of your loop.